Are there any theories of physics which assume the universe is fundamentally discrete?
Another way to phrase this is:  Are there any theories of physics which assume "There are no infinities or infinitesimals in real life" and develop the theory from that one axiom?
I know of one (Quantum-Geometry Dynamics, QGD, https://www.academia.edu/32577152/Quantum_Geometry_Dynamics_an_axiomatic_approach_to_physics ), but I am curious if there are any others.
I would like to compare them to see how they logically develop their theory of physics.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_gauge_theory

and develop the theory from that one axiom It may be possible to construct an abstract piece of mathematics from that one axiom (and I'm dubious it is), but that's not a theory in physics.  Physics has to match the universe we're in.

Seems like a big-list kind of question. How would you select one answer?

wolfram physics project https://www.wolframphysics.org/ and loop quantum gravity just came to my mind.

you cannot develop a theory just from that axiom, in will include every single theory that satisfy it, so you can only get generalities out of it, such as very few particular properties shared by all these theories ( the only things you will be able to prove). You need to add more axioms to focus on a more specific and detailed theory. That is how math and logic work/

Depends on what you mean, in at least two different ways. (1) Do you mean as a "fundamental" theory that is meant to be valid in all situations (an intrinsically slippery concept!) or as an "effective" theory that is only valid in some regime? (2) Do you require a theory of physics to actually make predictions that agree with experiments, or are you just looking for some speculative mathematical framework, eg an approach of quantum gravity but one which does not make predictions (even about classical gravity)?

StephenG, Sorry I simplified the question a little too much.  I meant "from that one axiom plus all known observations (which includes experimental results)".  I would distinguish observations as facts versus axioms as unprovable assumptions.  So after making that one unprovable assumption, the rest of the theory develops from explaining observations like "there is change in the universe".  The theory developer was trying to disprove the hypothesis "There are no infinities or infinitesimals in real life." but so far no contradiction.

Pato Galmarini, as I just commented to StephenG, the theory was also constrained by observations of the real world.  He was not trying to develop all possible theories where there are no infinities or infinitesimals, just see if that axiom was consistent with known observations.  Turns out so far it is, and explains those observations better than the standard model in many cases.  For example, one derived result was a way to calculate exact solutions to the N-Body Problem. Also, explanations for dark matter and dark energy naturally fall out of this theory.

Andrew, the theory developer had no ax to grind.  From that starting  point, he wanted to see how far he could get creating a fundamental theory of physics before running into a contradiction invalidating his hypothesis.  He knew that any proper theory would have to describe the world as it is, explain known experimental results, and make unique (compared to other theories) & falsifiable predictions.  And it does all three of those things.  My goal is to have someone smarter than I am look at the theory and see if they can find any issues with its logical development.

There is a classic 1987 paper by Y. Nambu titled "Field theory of Galois' fields".
A more recent contribution on the same topic is here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.4800
